# Putting SVG elements next to each other

Tags: html, web, svg

I have a `<text>` and a `<rect>` element nested in a `svg` element. I want the `<rect>` element to begin right after the `<text>` ends. But it looks like I have to position them using `x` and `y`.

Is there any way to put them next to each other like regular HTML elements ?

```
<svg>
<text>1200</text>
<rect width='120' height='12'></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: via javascript, call getComputedTextLength() to get the length of the text and set the rect x value to that.

Comment: Any pure HTML/CSS way of doing that ?

Comment: Only if the text is fixed and you work it out beforehand. Even then it's likely only to be right for one browser on one O/S

Comment: I get an error : Is not a function , I have the text element so I call the function on text element.

Comment: try with getBBox() then but getComputedTextLength()  seems to be pretty well supported by most browsers, so you might have a problem querying your element +you'll need to wait element be rendered before calling it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I only seem to be able to get it with this:

```
<svg height="30" width="100">
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">SVG TEXT!</text>
</svg>
<svg height="30" width="100">
   <rect width='120' height='12'></rect>
</svg>
```

See the Pen 'SVG Text and Box Test' by James Almeida here: http://codepen.io/jimmyplaysdrums/pen/ZYdEyw/